Group embedded array of documents only
in MongoDB I want to group an array of documents that is nested in another document without it affecting the parent document.
Database:
db={
      "users": [
        {
          "firstName": "David",
          "lastName": "Mueller",
          "messages": [
            {
              "text": "hello",
              "type": "PERSONAL"
            },
            {
              "text": "test",
              "type": "DIRECT"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Mia",
          "lastName": "Davidson",
          "messages": [
            {
              "text": "hello world",
              "type": "DIRECT"
            },
            {
              "text": ":-)",
              "type": "PERSONAL"
            },
            {
              "text": "hi there",
              "type": "DIRECT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

Desired result:
[
      {
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Mueller",
        "messages": [
          {
            "_id": "PERSONAL",
            "count": 1
          },
          {
            "_id": "DIRECT",
            "count": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Mia",
        "lastName": "Davidson",
        "messages": [
          {
            "_id": "PERSONAL",
            "count": 1
          },
          {
            "_id": "DIRECT",
            "count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
]

If I have an array of ids I already know how to do it using the internal pipeline of $lookup, but my question is how can I do that with an array of embedded documents.

This is an example of a working grouping on an array with ids using lookup. This is not the solution because the question is about an embedded document array and not an array of ids. This example is only provided to show that I can archive the desired result when ids instead of embedded documents are stored in an array.
Database for grouping with lookup:
db={
  "users": [
    {
      "firstName": "David",
      "lastName": "Mueller",
      "messages": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Mia",
      "lastName": "Davidson",
      "messages": [
        3,
        4,
        5
      ]
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "text": "hello",
      "type": "PERSONAL"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "text": "test",
      "type": "DIRECT"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "text": "hello world",
      "type": "DIRECT"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "text": ":-)",
      "type": "PERSONAL"
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "text": "hi there",
      "type": "DIRECT"
    }
  ]
}

Aggregation of grouping with lookup:
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "messages",
      "localField": "messages",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "messages",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$type",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])

Result of grouping with lookup (which is the desired result):
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Mueller",
    "messages": [
      {
        "_id": "PERSONAL",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "DIRECT",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000006"),
    "firstName": "Mia",
    "lastName": "Davidson",
    "messages": [
      {
        "_id": "PERSONAL",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": "DIRECT",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]

This example in the MongoDB playground

Now back to the issue: I want to archive the same result but with an embedded document array as provided at the top.
I cannot find out how to do this (I tried AI, lot's of google searches and other forums without success, you are my last resource before giving up), I know I can filter an embedded array using $addField and $fitler but not how I can group just the embedded array.
Please note that this is just a simple example my real data structure looks different and might also use other grouping functions like min, sum etc. but I just wanted to know a general way of archieving the same thing as when I use the lookup.
I appreciate any help with this and thank you 

did you try unwinding and grouping

here is an alternative without group and unwind https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYFTmaMXp_k

@cmgchess Nice one,You should post that as answer. Filtering/counting sub-docs on criteria is a common question; this is a good way to do it.

@aneroid please ignore the k,v nonsense i had done there. it could be simplified even further :D


Unwind messages

Use preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true in case the field is missing or empty.


Group by the _id (presumably userID) and message type; and set countType with $count.
Then re-group by _id only and use the first doc (since it's the same for non-message fields)

Push each {type: ..., count: countType} into a messages array.
Note that the documents are back to being one per user/_id


Set the doc.messages to the array messages which was pushed in the previous step.

Check for the first message not having a type - this occurs when the original document had missing or empty messages. If it is, then set it to the empty array, otherwise, use as-is.
Use any default you want, like [{ _id: null, count: 0 }]
(I've added an example doc in the playground which has one message but since it has a type it doesn't meet this criteria and is set correctly.)


Replace the root with the new doc which has all the correct info
(Optionally, sort on _id if you need it.)

db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$messages",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        type: "$messages.type"
      },
      countType: { $count: {} },
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      doc: { $first: "$doc" },
      messages: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id.type",
          count: "$countType"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "doc.messages": {
        // set it to some default missing message type
        $cond: {
          // `messages._id` will be missing
          if: {
            $eq: [
              { $type: { $first: "$messages._id" } },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          // put whichever "default" you want
          // like `[{ _id: null, count: 0 }]`
          then: [],
          else: "$messages"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$doc" }
])

Mongo Playground
Mongo Playground with minNumber
Previous demo playground if messages is never missing and never empty.

I noticed there is an issue with count when it comes to empty and null arrays (with preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true at the unwind). It will always count 1 (instead of 0) because the parent document is present.
I solved it by
a contidional set of 1 which is then summed up
$set: { "messages.count": { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$messages" }, then: 1, else: "$messages.count" } } } and
countType: { $sum: "$messages.count" },
https://mongoplayground.net/p/_c45uSCsq08
Don't know if there is a better way but other accumulators seem to work fine

What do you want the result to be when messages is missing? messages: [{ _id: null, count: 0 }] or just messages: [] ?

In my current use messages missing and empty are treated the same way, which probably means messages: [{ _id: null, count: 0 }]

I've updated the answer for messages being empty or missing. You can set default you want for those cases, see the $set stage.

thanks a lot @aneroid

here is an alternative way of doing without group and unwind.

$setUnion: "$messages.type" will give a list of the unique $messages.type so now you are essentially looping it using $map
In each iteration of the loop I return an object in the form of {_id, count}. To calculate the count I'm filtering the initial messages array based on the type and getting the size of the filtered array

db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      messages: {
        $map: {
          input: { $setUnion: "$messages.type" },
          as: "type",
          in: {
            _id: "$$type",
            count: {
              $size: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$messages",
                  as: "msg",
                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$msg.type", "$$type" ] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

playground
The above query will make sense if you could understand this. This is how i came up with the logic actually :)


const db={ "users": [ { "firstName": "David", "lastName": "Mueller", "messages": [ { "text": "hello", "type": "PERSONAL" }, { "text": "test", "type": "DIRECT" } ] }, { "firstName": "Mia", "lastName": "Davidson", "messages": [ { "text": "hello world", "type": "DIRECT" }, { "text": ":-)", "type": "PERSONAL" }, { "text": "hi there", "type": "DIRECT" } ] } ] }
    
const res = db.users.map(user => {
  const uniqTypes = [...new Set(user.messages.map(msg => msg.type))];
  const messages = uniqTypes.map(type => {
    const count = user.messages.filter(msg => msg.type === type).length;
    return {_id: type, count};
  })
  return {...user, messages};
})
    
console.log(res)




This looks also like a very interesting way to do it thank you. I chose the other answer because it uses the group aggregation so that it is more similar to the lookup approach, but I will definitely keep this in mind.

@LDK yeah unwind+group is the more common way of doing things. Maybe this might help in situations where the aggregation pipeline stage can exceed 100MB due to an unwind

I'm not sure how much memory would be an issue (I tested an unwind on a multi-GB project, no problems). Rather, the repeated group-by in my answer is a performance concern. So I'd be curious about how many docs or how large array-fields is the pivot where one solution is better than the other. Also, the approach in this answer works very well even with deeply nested arrays of documents; rather than multiple unwinds followed by multiple group's to re-construct the original documents.
